# Bing search page locks up (the front page, not results)

Tags: firefox, internet, web, search-engines, bing

I'm encountering a strange problem.  I've been using the Bing search engine for a while now, and have been happy with it.  I still am.  However, starting either last night or early today, when the Bing front page (www.bing.com) loads, it locks up.

I can still enter search terms and successfully get searchable results.  However, absolutely none of the links that would normally be moused-over work. The cursor doesn't even change.  What I have been able to find is that in the short time between the page loading and the bottom bar rising (that thing with "Popular Now" "Search History" etc.), the links work.  But as soon as that bar finds its place, the page locks down.

Any ideas on how to fix this?  I can't think of anything that's changed.  I'm running Firefox 18.0.1 on a 32bit Windows 7 system.

Thanks much.

Comment: What’s the bottom bar? I don’t see anything such in my bing.

Comment: This thing: http://img842.imageshack.us/img842/2526/ss130129203558.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I can see that this didn't become a popular question to answer, but I'll note that I found the problem.  The RealDownloader 1.3.0 addon for Firefox was mucking with it.  I don't know *WHY* if was causing the problem, but going through the iterations of possibilities has shown that it is clearly that addon.  Disable it, and everything works correctly.

So... thank you for anyone who at least looked at this post.